# Can one represent Dirac's delta distribution as an integral over $\mathbb{R}$ other than the Fourier transform of 1?

Tags: fourier-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, integral-transforms

I have come across a problem from mathematical physics which asks me to find all real (smooth, say) functions $g(\cdot)$ such that

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{ig(xy)}dx=\delta (y)\,,
$$

where $\delta (\cdot )$ is Dirac's distribution.

It is obvious that we can pick
$$ 
g(xy)=\pm xy \, ,
$$

but I need to know whether these are the *only* solutions. Unfortunately, I am unable to conclude that the relation given above    forces $g (\cdot )$ to be a linear function - maybe it does not!

The difficulty stems from the fact that one cannot use the (generalized) orthogonality of the exponentials $e^{ixy}$ to "undo" the integral on the left.

**Update 1**

Assuming $g(u)=p+qu+ru^2$ with non-zero $p,q,r \in \mathbb R$, the integral on the left can be evaluated using the Fourier transform of a complex Gaussian. The result is not a Dirac-$\delta$, so the function $g(\cdot )$ cannot be a quadratic polynomial.

Clinging at straws... A conceptual insight seems necessary rather than a computation.

**Appendix**

The original post started with a little detour which I reproduce here: I was looking for all (smooth, say) functions $f(x,y)$ such that

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{if(x,y)}dx=\delta (y)\,.
$$

Rescaling $y\to ay$ with $a\neq 0$, one can derive
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{if(\frac{x}{a},\,ay)}dx=\delta (y)\,,
$$

which suggests that we should have $f(x,y)=g(xy)$ - otherwise the left-hand-side depends on $a$ while the right-hand-side would not (one can probably make this argument more rigorous).

Comment: Consider the following Hankel transform: $\text{HankelTransform}[J_0(x),x,y+1]=\int\limits_0^\infty x\ J_0(x)\ J_0(x\ (y+1))\,dx=\delta(y)$.

Comment: Also consider the following Mellin transform evaluated at $s=i\ t-1$: $\frac{1}{2 \pi}\mathcal{M}_x[x](i\ t-1)=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int\limits_0^\infty x\ x^{(i\ t-1)-1}\ dx=\delta (t)$.

Comment: @StevenClark : Thank you for your remarks. Unfortunately, I do not see how these transforms would help me to identify the functions $g(xy)$ I am looking for. Maybe I am missing something obvious?

Comment: If $g$ is a real-valued function, then $e^{ig(xy)}$ has absolute value $1$, so that the integral in question diverges. So you'd have to explain in which sense this integration is understood.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks - the integral is, of course, understood in a distributional sense. I try to make this clear by adding to the text that the RHS of the equation is a Dirac-$\delta$.

Comment: Hah this question is very tangentially related to some research I'm doing. What I would do is first recast your problem as a proper distribution theoretic problem so that you can do actual analysis on it. Just phrasing it as a divergent integral is all well and good, but if you want to be able to interact with $g$ in any meaningful way, you'll need to take an inner product with test functions.

Comment: Thank you @CameronWilliams . Sure, a more rigorous setting of the problem might be useful although I do not currently see it generating new ideas in my head (probably only due to my lack of experience & imagination). I'll see what I can come up with.